# How to set span full width inside button ? css

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap and custom CSS for buttons but.

```
 <button type="button"
        class="dropdown-item"  >  
        <span (click)="showI('test_data)"  
        class="text-capitalize">
        {{ selectedAction(singleBook.href) }} 
       </span>
     </button>
```

What is the problem? The button is 200px width. And the span is only 50px width and the rest of the button is not clickable ...
I want my span button to take up the entire width of the button to full of width...

no work example : width: 100%; or max-width: 100% ...

Comment: why don't you add click event on button not the span ?

Comment: i have another click action on button.. i need to set span 100% width

Comment: so why don't you combine your 2 click actions into 1 action :)

Comment: is there a reason why you want to do it this way? Because you could tie the click event to the button.

Answer (score 0):

[Span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) by default is not a block element, you need to set it manually via CSS, span by default is an inline element.

```
span.text-capitalize {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this is no work :/

Comment: Can you add more info? Because it works on the given test [https://jsfiddle.net/8ksqx3ah/](https://jsfiddle.net/8ksqx3ah/)

Answer (score 0):

Answer of @GhostPengy doesn't work because button has padding in it. If we remove the padding:

```css
.dropdown-item {
    padding: 0px;
}
.text-capitalize {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="dropdown-item"  >  
    <span (click)="showI('test_data)"  class="text-capitalize">
        {{ selectedAction(singleBook.href) }} 
    </span>
</button>
```

It works like you want it to.